# Why this integral is confusing?

Tags: integration

I am a bit confusing.

What is the value of this integral?

$$I(x)=\int0\mathrm{d}x$$

Is it $0$ or $C$ where $C$ is a constant?

We have: $\mathrm{d}I(x)/\mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{d}C/\mathrm{d}x=0$

Comment: If you're doing an indefinite integral, then it's $C$.

Comment: When doing an indefinite integral you are asking for _any_ function whose derivative matches the integrand. Hence _every_ indefinite integral will give you an extra _arbitrary_ constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int\lambda dx=\lambda x+C$$
so in your case $\lambda=0$ and
$$\int 0dx=C$$

Comment: But $C$ must be $0$, No?

Comment: No not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome @x.y.z...

Comment: $C=\int 0 dx=0\int 1dx=0$. Sorry to disturb you again but Am I wrong?

Comment: @x.y.z... I agree with you, see my answer

Comment: @x.y.z... you can't bring $0$ outside the integral..

Comment: You're right since I deal with anti-derivative and not an integral@Ant

Answer (score 1):

If it is an indefinite integral, the integral is $C$.  If it is a definite integral, i.e.
$$\int_a^b0\,dx$$
for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then it is $0$.   We can see this with the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$$
where $F'(x)=f(x)$.  Notice that $C$ is an anti-derivative of $0$ so 
$$\int_a^b0\,dx=C|_a^b=C-C=0.$$

Comment: Why the downvote?